# Alternatives for <link rel="canonical"..> in body

Tags: html5-canvas, canonical-link

I am wondering if there is an alternative for canonical links in the header of a page? I am asking this because usually a canonical links looks like this:

```
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.google.com" />
</head>
```

On one of my current projects I am unable to set those canonical links in the head of my site. Why is unnecessary right now, I am looking for a workaround where I can inform search robots about a canonical link in the body of my site?

I tried it like this:

```
<link itemprop="url" href="https://www.google.com">
```

But when I use the canonical link checker here (https://www.seoreviewtools.com/canonical-url-location-checker/) I am getting the info that no canonical links are found on my site.

Any ideas? Are there alternatives outside the header part of a page?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does really no one has an idea?

Comment: Why can't you set them in the `<head>`?   If Google allowed them in the body, any site with an XSS vulnerability would be vulnerable to hackers maliciously inserting canonical tags to refer search engines away from the site.

Comment: While this question does have a small amount of programming in it and it is on-topic here at StackOverflow, you would probably have gotten better answers if you had asked this on [webmasters.se].